# Downgrade from Gazebo 4

Tags: gazebo-4, gazebo-3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm trying to downgrade from Gazebo 4 to Gazebo 3 and make it work with ROS Indigo. I'm using the following steps:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-latest.list'
wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-$distro-gazebo4-ros-pkgs
```

The problem is that I get the message "E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-gazebo3-ros-pkgs". What am I doing wrong in the steps I'm using?

UPDATE: Does the package ros-indigo-gazebo3-ros-pkgs actually exist?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7332/downgrade-from-gazebo-4/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-10-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2014-10-29**:
There is no `ros-indigo-gazebo3-ros-pkgs`.
Can you say what problem exists in Gazebo 4 that makes you want to downgrade?

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-29**:
Please see this issue (http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7293/robot-that-worked-in-gazebo-2-fails-to-launch-in/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can install the gazebo3 package and [build gazebo_ros_pkgs from source](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing&cat=connect_ros#B.InstallfromSource%28onUbuntu%29) on trusty.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) on 2014-10-30**:
Try installing `libgazebo-dev` as well

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-30**:
Excellent, thank you both. Sorry for the repeated comments. Something went wrong with the network on my end.